# How to validate for Address Zero in Ink1 4.0

Tags: ink

Previously in Ink! 3, in a function which is accepting AccountId as a parameter, One can validate that the address passed is not AddressZero by using .is_zero() on the parameter variable name but I can't do on my current Ink! 4 project... Honestly would want to step down to Ink3!

Comment: Little context why this has been removed: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1255

Answer (score 7):

An easy method you can use to get the AddressZero is [this](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/integration-tests/erc1155/lib.rs#L587):

```
fn zero_address() -> AccountId {
    [0u8; 32].into()
}
```

And compare it to another address, see an example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/integration-tests/erc1155/lib.rs#L435):

```
ensure!(to != zero_address(), Error::ZeroAddressTransfer);
```